# Limit of sequence of bounded functions with supremum metric

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions, metric-spaces

Let $(g_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $(B(S),d_\infty)$ (which is the set of bounded real-valued functions on a set $S$, equipped with the supremum metric) that converges to $g \in B(S)$ where $|g(s)|\geqslant m\ \forall s\in S$.

How do I show that $\sup_{s\in S} |\frac{1}{g_n(s)}| \leqslant \frac{2}{m} $ for large enough $n$?

This is just stated in the middle of a proof I’m looking at but I can’t see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to say that $g_n \to g$.

Choose $n_0$ such that $|g_n(s) -g(s)|<\frac  m 2$ for all $s$ if $n >n_0$. Then $|g_n(s)| \geq |g(s)|-|g_n(s) -g(s)| \geq m-\frac m 2=\frac  m 2$. Hence $|\frac 1 {g_n(s)}| \leq \frac  2 m$ for $n >n_0$.

Comment: Sorry. I will edit it.

Comment: But $|g_n(s) - g(s)| \leqslant |g_n(s)| + |g(s)|$ so $|g_n(s) - g(s)| - |g(s)| \leqslant |g_n(s)|$.

Comment: Where does your inequality come from?

Comment: It's the triangle inequality for $g_n(s)$ and $g(s) - g_n(s)$. That means $|g(s)|= |g_n(s) + g(s)-g_n(s)| \le |g_n(s)| + |g(s)-g_n(s)|$. Then it follows with trival reoderings of the terms.